# Creat a new dataframe that has two columns of one dataframe when some rows matches with another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two big dataframes. “gene” has structure like this (more than three columns though):

```
Mutation ID   CDS         Mutation AA
COSM1000525   123         V617A 
COSM1003371   234         S517A
COSM1003372   456         T417A
COSM1004880   567         K317A
COSM1004881   1234        R610A
COSM1004883   1234        V617A
COSM1004884   543         W617A
COSM1006396   132         Y617A
COSM1007340   7654        V617A
```

“output” is part of "gene" and only has one column `Mutation ID`:

```
Mutation ID             
COSM1000525   
COSM1003372                   
COSM1004881
```

I want to make a new dataframe that has two columns (`Mutation ID` and `Mutation AA`) of the “gene’ when Mutation ID matches with those in the “output”.

How to implement this in python?

Comment: If you'll be working more with these kind of data, and since you already mention dataframe (though you didn't tag your question with `pandas`), have a read through the [merge, join and concatenate section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) of the Pandas documentation.

Comment: It's a good idea to show your attempt in a [MCVE format](/help/MCVE).  A few good reasons include letting others find more details, as well as not wasting their time to try the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) is a good guide.

```
mut_filter = set(output['Mutation ID'])
df = gene.loc[gene['Mutation'].isin(mut_filter), ['Mutation ID', 'Mutation AA']]
```